# How to get specific columns from stored procedure return in .NET 6 and EF 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

Recently I updated my app to .net 6 and entity framework to 6.0.5 but some of my functionalities crashed which is expected. Namely, before this I was using entity framework 3.1.3. In my app I have many calls to stored procedures and most of them return a set from which I select the needed columns and then return the result. In 3.1.3 I used to do it this way:

```
return await _context.SOME_VIEW.FromSqlRaw("EXEC core.ProcName @P", parameter)
       .Select(x => new ClassA()
       {
           P = x.P,
           D = x.D,
           F = x.F,
           T = x.T
       }).ToListAsync();
```

However, now this throws me

> "'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side."

I did some research and found that if I do it like

```
return await _context.ClassA.FromSqlRaw("EXEC core.ProcName @P", 
parameter).ToListAsync();
```

then it works. What worries here is that if I choose to go with this approach, I'll have to do ALOT of changes in my code which I'm trying to avoid. Is there a way to keep the old way of calling stored procedures with entity framework 6.0.5?

Comment: You are doing what the error tells you to do and fetch it to the client and do the select there. Try to select only specific columns from a SPRoc in raw SQL and you'll see.
Once you have it in memory on the client, you can do whatever you want - but the operation is no longer executed on the db.

Comment: Isn't this a worse approach? Because if I go with AsEnumerable, I'll need to load the whole payload in my app's memory and then filter from there. So there's no way I can fix this the way it is now, except by adding AsEnumerable?

Comment: i really do not see what is the downfall of what now does EF 6.0 for you. 
Before from raw world (untyped) and impossible to track entity world.

All the sudden, you have a rigtht of the bat a DbSet<ClassA> - which offers you all IQueryable operator for free. so you do not even need to go to ToListAsync and stuff - maybe you should consider changing your code to match what EF propose

Comment: @anthino12 you can wrap your SProc in a `Select Into #tmpTable` and return that. You can select specific columns from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way of keeping the old calling pattern.

EF Core Power Tools can do the mappings for you automatically, maybe it can ease the transition?